# ¿Cómo cargar respuesta de una consulta a un input type radio?

Tags: php, html5

Tengo una consulta relacionada al uso del input type radio y es que estoy haciendo un formulario para crear un item (en el formulario tengo inputs de texto y los radio button como también un select)y mediante una tabla presento los valores que se le ha dado. En una consulta con `php` ya recupero los datos de la tupla que se encuentran en una tabla de la base de datos y ya tengo creadas variables que contienen cada uno de los respectivos valores y ya se los estoy poniendo en las etiquetas mediante el atributo `value` en cada una de ellas y me he quedado estancado ya que no tengo idea de como hacer que un determinado radio button se marque según el valor que tiene especificado en la etiqueta, es decir: en una variable ya tengo almacenado el valor de 1 pero no tengo la mayor idea de cómo hacer que se marque el input que sea igual a la variable.

```
<?php
   include("db.php");
   
   if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
       $query = "SELECT ....";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
       if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
           $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
           $destacado = $fila['destacado'];
       }
   }

?>
```

```
<tr>
    <td class="descripcion"><label for="destacado"><strong>Destacado</strong></label></td>
    <td class="cajaTxt">
        <input type="radio" name="destacado" value="0">
        <label for="0">NO</label>
        <input type="radio" name="destacado" value="1">
        <label for="1">SI</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Creo que parte de una solución es con el uso de una sentencia `if` pero no tengo idea de como recuperar los id de los inputs cuando ya se los especifique.

**¿Talvez alguien ya haya tenido la oportunidad de encontrarse en un inconveniente similar que me pueda guiar?**

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de llegar a lo que buscas, pero con la escasa información que nos ofreces, haré mi mejor esfuerzo.

Por lo que veo, solo esperas una fila como resultado de la consulta:

`if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {...}`

Dices que ya tienes almacenado el valor en la variable `$destacado`. Luego, tal como lo mencionas, puedes usar un condicional `if`, de tal manera que si `$destacado` es igual a 1, marcas el input como **checked** (*que equivale al atributo que requieren los `input` de tipo `radio` para estar seleccionados*)...

`<?= $destacado == 1 ? 'checked' : '';?>`

Con esto en mente (*y asumiendo que recibes el valor de la variable `$destacado` en tu código `html`*), vamos a ver cómo se asignaría este atributo al `input`:

```
<input type="radio" name="destacado" value="0" <?= $destacado == 0 ? 'checked' : '';?>>
<label for="0">NO</label>
<input type="radio" name="destacado" value="1" <?= $destacado == 1 ? 'checked' : '';?>>
<label for="1">SI</label>
```

Como te menciono, existen formas mucho mas limpias de hacerlo, pero no cuento con suficientes detalles para darte una respuesta mas precisa.

El resultado, siguiendo tu ejemplo, debería ser similar al siguiente:

```html
<input type="radio" name="destacado" value="0">
<label for="0">NO</label>
<input type="radio" name="destacado" value="1" checked>
<label for="1">SI</label>
```